# Grep and delete file

Tags: linux, grep, find

I run the following code to delete malware, I would like to extend it with a pipe so it can delete the files that found to contain the string below (delete result return by grep).

```
grep -rnw . -e "ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718"
```

It return a list of files

```
./gallery.php:2:if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718'))
./gallery.php:4:define('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718', 1);
./wp-includes/SimplePie/HTTP/db.php:2:if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718'))
./wp-includes/SimplePie/HTTP/db.php:4:define('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718', 1);
./wp-includes/SimplePie/Parse/template.php:2:if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718'))
./wp-includes/SimplePie/Parse/template.php:4:define('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718', 1);
./wp-includes/SimplePie/XML/file.php:2:if (!defined('ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718'))
```

Comment: try using the `-l` option to`grep` to only list the file names.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet if i use -l, how do i execute it with a rm -rf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `xargs` to process files as they are listed from stdin.

Grep recursively searches the contents of `.` for the pattern (you don't seem to be using any regex features, so I changed the flag to `-F` for fixed string).

Here's a simple script that will delete the files, note that it will split on all newlines, including newlines in file names.

```
$ grep -rl -F "ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718" . | \
    xargs -I'{}' rm '{}'
```

For the sake of completeness, here's a command that will work regardless of file name (using `rm` is safe because we know the path MUST begin with `./`)

```
$ find . -type f -exec \
    /bin/sh -c 'grep -q -F "$0" "$1" && rm "$1"' 'ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718' '{}' \;
```

and deleting multiple files at once.

```
$ find . -type f -exec \
    /bin/sh -c 'grep -q -F "$0" "$@" && rm "$@"' 'ALREADY_RUN_1bc29b36f342a82aaf6658785356718' '{}' +
```